# Neo4J Enterprise 3.0.4 Indefinite Hang, Recovery Requires Restart

Tags: neo4j

Neo4J enterprise is hanging indefinitely.  Recovery requires a Neo4J restart.  We use Python scripts with py2neo to ingest public data into Neo4J enterprise 3.0.4.  So far we have been unable to complete the ingestion script.  Before the script completes, Neo4J hangs indefinitely.  There is nothing interesting in the logs.   If we try the browser, the busy cursor appears and spins.  This problem started for us when we upgraded from 3.0.2 to 3.0.4.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?  For now, we'll try reverting the Neo4J release and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Your question lacks all and any vital information, like how you ingest data (code, queries) and thread dump of how things look like when hanging.

Comment: We read articles with associated metadata (abstract, description, publish date) and relationships (author, journal).  We use py2neo's merge() method to push the entities and relationships to Neo4J.    We have not performed a thread-dump yet.  We were canvasing to see if anyone else has seen these hangs.  We'll work on a thread dump next and post here with an update.  Thanks.